# rgbdslam/rgbdslam_ros_ui.h not found

Tags: ros, rgbdslam-freiburg, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build my own SLAM project using some of RGBDSLAM code. After I copied some modules I went to compile using rosmake, but it threw me this error

```
rgbdslam/rgbdslam_ros_ui.h: No such file or directory
```

I figurd this is happening because I am missing something about service generation. Can anyone guide me how to do that. BTW, I have the following line uncommented in CMakeLists

```
rosbuild_gensrv()
```

But I have no idea how to make it recognize the rgbdslam folder in src.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54246/rgbdslam/rgbdslam_ros_ui.h-not-found/) by [DonaldV](https://answers.ros.org/users/2920/donaldv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is probably not the best solution, but you could try adding this line in your CmakeList.txt : `include_directories(~/YOUR-PATH/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/srv_gen/cpp/include)`

---

Originally posted by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) with karma: 735 on 2013-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DonaldV](https://answers.ros.org/users/2920/donaldv/) on 2013-02-05**:
Thank you for pointing me in right direction. I didn't use that solution, but I made some changes about include directories in my CMakeLists.txt with help from the same file of rgbdslam, and it helped!

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2013-02-05**:
I'm glad it helped you. Would you be able to share your solution? I have a similar problem, I get this error: fatal error: linux/compiler.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated. I have added this include_directories(/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-35-generic/include/linux) but doesn't work